# retrieve data inside script with xpath

Tags: xpath

I'd like to retrieve the number after the attribute "ean13" inside the category:

```
<script>

    universal_variable['product'] = {
        id: 29363,
        ean13: '4005900288646',
        name: 'Cellular Perfect Skin Cuidado De Día Fp 15',
        brand: 'Nivea',
        price: 13.97,
        old_price: 19.95,
        active: 1,
        categories: 'Cremas Hidratantes y Antiedad, Cuidado Facial, Higiene y Belleza',
        url: 'https://www.ulabox.com/producto/cellular-perfect-skin-cuidado-de-dia-fp-15/29363',
                    image: 'https://static.ulabox.com/media/62855_l1.jpg'
            };

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to get `4005900288646`

```
//script/substring-before(substring-after(., "ean13: '"), "',")
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that should be supported by xpath 1.0 ... I believe your code works only for 2.0 but thanks anyways

Comment: @AdriàTC , In case of XPath 1.0 I guess it would be better to get complete text from `script` node and using programming language features (like string split or regex) extract required substring